# Service Workers

Tags: nodejs, flutter, backend, service-workers

He estado desarrollando una aplicación y en busca de una solución para un problema que surgió, me encontré con el concepto de Service workers. Lo que entiendo es que es como un intrmediario entre el servidor y el cliente para poder manejar peticiones y realizar ciertas acciones. Me interesó porque decía que eran comúnmente usadas para enviar y recibir push notifications.

Sin embargo, investigando más, me encontré con que son usadas en aplicaciones web progresivas y lo que las hace especiales es que pueden guardar información en caché, haciendo estas apps más rápidas y pudiendo brindar un servicio aún sin conexión a internet.

Yo las busqué porque necesitaba encontrar un diseño que me permitiera gestionar el envío de miles de notificaciones a muchos usuarios, pero no estoy muy segura de si esto me va a ser de ayuda. Me podrían decir por favor si es recomendable usar este modelo en una aplicación móvil nativa que hace consultas a un servidor web para poder realizar tareas, entre ellas, el envío de notificaciones?
Gracias

Comment: No tiene mucha importancia en cuantos usuarios envías notificaciones, sino que si vas a recibir notificaciones si o si necesitas un service worker

Comment: Por otra parte tu pregunta puede quedar cerrada por estar basada en opiniones y no es adecuado para este sitio, lo mejor es visitar el chat (cuando tengas mayor reputación podrás entrar)